# High CPU and Memory with 2 million glass disposables

Tags: glass-mapper, performance-optimization

We have been seeing the high CPU and constant growth of memory. When analyzing the memory dump I noticed that the memory is occupied by 2 million Glass Mapper objects.

Has anyone faced this issue and has possible fixes?

We are using Glass Mapper version **"4.3.4.197"** and Sitecore 8.2 update 1:

Below is finding from sitecore

Based on provided dump, top memory consumer is glass mapper. Here is a list of most memory consuming types, consuming from 25MB to 300MB in descending order
[image: Heap View]

**UPDATE:**
Looking at memory dump, the Validation Factory Below is holding all the glass objects. And this factory is referenced by Autofac Root.

Any suggestion on how this code below can be fixed?

```
public class AutofacValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
    {
        private readonly IComponentContext _context;

        public AutofacValidatorFactory(IComponentContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
        {
            object instance;
            if (!_context.TryResolve(validatorType, out instance)) return null;
            return instance as IValidator;
        }
    }

public class ValidationModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(ThisAssembly)
                   .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Validator"))
                   .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                   .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider>().As<ModelValidatorProvider>();

            builder.RegisterType<AutofacValidatorFactory>().As<IValidatorFactory>();

            base.Load(builder);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
Completely got rid of slow AUTOFAC but still seeing memory growth. I've created a separate question for that:

[Sitecore 8.2 memory leak - SitecoreRequestScopeModule holding many objects](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/22409/sitecore-8-2-memory-leak-sitecorerequestscopemodule-holding-many-objects)

Comment: I don't think it's glass mapper. thousands of people use it around the world. I do assume it's some of your code which is holding references to glass mapper objects and that's why they are not picked up by garbage collector

Comment: I have seen this in the past when you DI up a glass instance and dispose of it improperly. Or you are are newing up some glass references in a static method. Either way, its not glass. Its your code.

Comment: Sitecore Support provided this link hence thought of asking:
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/874459

Glasss DI comes out of the box and we scanned through out the project and didn't find any static method holding reference to glass

Comment: Updated finding from sitecore support..

Comment: Perhaps add some code around this scenario?

Comment: MarekMusielak and @MarkGibbons , I've updated the question with latest finding. Yes, doesn't look like glass. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you will need to review each validator that is created by the factory. You need to see if a validator itself is maintaining a reference which is itself maintained by the factory.

Comment: Are you using GlassCast method in your code to cast items into GlassMapper objects?

Comment: @jjczopek, yes we do on quite places. Have you had bad experience with it?

Answer (score 1):

We have experienced something like that once on production environment, after some period of time servers were running out of memory. With help with Sitecore support, they pointed out we have a lot of GlassMapper objects, coming from casting items into GlassMapper objects.

We have created custom extension method:

```
public static T GlassCast<T>(this Item item, bool isLazy = false, bool inferType = false) where T : class
{
    var service = (SitecoreService) ContainerManager.Container.Resolve<ISitecoreService>(item.Database.Name);
    return service.Cast<T>(item, isLazy, inferType);
}
```

We have `ISitecoreService` registered as Singleton in Windsor container.

```
container.Register(Component.For<ISitecoreService>().ImplementedBy<SitecoreService>().LifestyleSingleton()
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("databaseName", "web")).Named("web"));
```

Comment: Thank @jjczopek, good point. But we have already handled this one.